# Remove extra Google Maps script

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, google-maps

I'm developing a plugin that use a Google Maps API. The plugin enqueuing script in this way:

`wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize&language=en-us', array('jquery'), false, true);`

Considering the fact that other plugins/themes may use same maps library, while `$handle` could be different, the validation `wp_script_is($handle,'registered')` does not makes sence. Duplicating of enqueued script leads to JS error:
`You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

Regarding things described I've build a code that search thought `$wp_scripts` for Google Maps scripts and unset it, in case if found:

```
global $wp_scripts;
foreach ($wp_scripts->registered as $key => $script) {
    if (preg_match('#maps\.google(?:\w+)?\.com/maps/api/js#', $script->src)) {
        unset($wp_scripts->registered[$key]);
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I check and reassign dependencies of the removed scripts (in case if they're set by other plugins/themes). What will happens and how to deal with the fact that multiple plugins may use the same `&callback=initialize` parameter of Google Maps API script.

Comment: Maybe localize script could contain a collection of different callbacks, then you only enqueue a script that points to your collection callback which will cycle through all initializers in JS. You just need to parse off the original callbacks in any currently registered scripts before you dequeue them.

Comment: what about using your js file included in your plugin then check if var *google.maps.Load* is exist (or any unique var or class google map used) >> if not exist you can getScript from google .... I don't know if worked but i like your question

Comment: Good suggestions! I'll try to workaround using this and make a report. With all the respect to @Mark Kaplun's answer i'm not a supporter of "leave as it is" is terms of development.

Comment: Why not create an option for the user to choose whether or not to include the API with your plugin. If they are including it somewhere else then they can just turn yours off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT :** 
use `wp_enqueue_script` as you want (enqueue in header or footer after jQuery as you want) to enqueue file called something like : `gmap.js` included in your plugin

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-gmap', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'inc/js/gmap.js', array('jquery'), false, true);//just change your path and name of file
```

write this in your Js file :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
        return;
    }else{
        $.getScript( 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js', function() {});
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/khaled-sadek/pen/WwvOGb

Comment: Thank you for solution provided, but it does not answer in terms of enqueueing the script. For example what if i'll need to put gmaps script in the footer or right after jquery.

Comment: @Ignet B. ok update the answer , the key is use specific js file to this mission and enqueueing it as you like

Answer (score 5):

Don't stress about it. There are many ways in which plugins and themes can break each other and you just can not avoid it when everything happens in the same execution space/context.

You should test against whatever plugins and themes you want to make sure your code works with but there is just no way to make everybody at every point in time happy. Actually it is kind of hubris from your side to decide that your enqueue should be given priorities over others....

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer. I understand that it's not fair to block other plugins enqueues, due to that my question where asked: want to enqueue in a smooth way to cooperate with plugins, avodigin errors. 

Looks like i'd let things go and simply test with top-used plugins.

Comment: @Mark but if can help avoid such conflicts in the first place? finding a way to detect and workaround potential conflicts is better than trying to be compatible with X themes/plugins which is basically futile.

Comment: @majick, it is not your problem as a plugin author. As I said it is hubris to assume your code is more important then the code in other plugins. If there is a collision then the site owner will see it when he activates the plugin and will probably deactivate it. If it is such a small problem that the site owner can not even see it, then there is nothing to fix in the first place

Comment: how does that help? assuming the site owner can see there is a conflict, it is then left to them to deactivate one plugin or the other, or find a way to fix the conflict themselves. this kind of foresight for a plugin author should be encouraged not written off as "not my problem" = this is why conflicts happen in the first place.

Comment: @majick, I don't get your point. I have two plugins on my site A and B. When both active the site goes blank. How can anyone which is not the site owner know which plugin is more important to the site?

Comment: If plugins A and B both use shared resource C - as in this question! - there is no need for them to conflict, and simply checking like this helps avoid conflicts, so that the blank screen doesn't happen in the first place, and the site owner doesn't have to decide which is more important because they can just use both.

Comment: @majick, seems like you never had conflicting plugins and themes.

Comment: You are joking right? If they were coded better like this in the first place I wouldn't have had to fix so many, lol. And as I recall, I *have* had this exact problem happen with Google Maps once, and simply dequeued one of the scripts so both plugins worked. If code like in these answers was present in either of the plugins there would have been no problem.

Comment: So you never had plugins that used CSS style that didn't work well with the theme you were using? plugin that had a function named "my_init" as the init hook? You are so lucky

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing a script if it has already been enqueued, you could combine your answer to check for the Google Maps script and add the fallback to the javascript check suggested by @Kiki...

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','google_maps_script_loader',999);

function google_maps_script_loader() {
    global $wp_scripts; $gmapsenqueued = false;
    foreach ($wp_scripts->registered as $key => $script) {
        if (preg_match('#maps\.google(?:\w+)?\.com/maps/api/js#', $script->src)) {
            $gmapsenqueued = true;
        }
    }

    if ($gmapsenqueued) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-gmap', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'inc/js/gmap.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize&language=en-us', array('jquery'), false, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions, but i think this function should be hoocked to run after all plugins & theme enqueueing their script

Comment: ok I've added the hook to the edit...